# what are the predefined Ruby on rails parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web

I've noticed some predefined url parameters in my rails app.

These parameter are:

- **:template** (use to display views),
- **:controller** (use to call rails controller).

My question is what are the other predefined url parameters?

Comment: sample ```def index
        render params[:template];
        end``` ```get 'users/:template' => 'users#index'```

Comment: rails principle is convention over configuration. this means you can overwrite any parameters. but as far as i know "reserved" are :controller, :action and maybe :id for rest. but still, it's up to you to use any of them